# Why can't I run a simple ping from the IBM Liberty Docker image

Tags: docker, websphere-liberty

I am learning about IBM Containers and Docker.  I created a 2-line Docker file to test it out:

```
FROM registry-ice.ng.bluemix.net/ibmliberty
CMD ["ping","google.com"]
```

Unfortunately, when I run a container from this image, it gives the following output:

```
> docker run liberty-ping
Usage: ping [-aAbBdDfhLnOqrRUvV] [-c count] [-i interval] [-I interface]
        [-m mark] [-M pmtudisc_option] [-l preload] [-p pattern] [-Q tos]
        [-s packetsize] [-S sndbuf] [-t ttl] [-T timestamp_option]
        [-w deadline] [-W timeout] [hop1 ...] destination
```

When I changed the FROM line to `FROM ubuntu:trusty`, the ping executed flawlessly.  What is going on?

Comment: Try `CMD [ "google.com"]`. Probably have an `ENTRYPOINT` in the source image messing with your image.

Comment: Please run `docker inspect registry-ice.ng.bluemix.net/ibmliberty` and look for the entrypoint. Would you expect that entrypoint to accept "ping" and "google.com" as arguments?  Compare that with the entrypoint on `ubuntu:trusty`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to the friendly comments, I found the websphere-liberty Dockerfile does include an Entrypoint: https://github.com/WASdev/ci.docker/blob/master/websphere-liberty/8.5.5/developer/Dockerfile#L57

Reading the Dockerfile reference at http://docs.docker.com/reference/builder/#cmd I understood that there was an option that executes the parameters based on an ENTRYPOINT, but I didn't realize that the other two flavors of the CMD syntax wouldn't work when an ENTRYPOINT was set.

I changed the dockerfile to this:

```
FROM registry-ice.ng.bluemix.net/ibmliberty
ENTRYPOINT ["/bin/ping"]
CMD ["google.com"]
```

Now it works!